# Sunrise and sunset

Tags: code-golf, math

I'm a bit of a romantic, I love taking my wife out to see the sunrises and sunsets in the place we are located. For the sake of this exercise let's say I don't have code that can tell me the time of either sunset or sunrise for whatever date, latitude and longitude I would happen to be in.

Your task, coders, is to generate the smallest code possible that takes a decimal latitude and longitude (taken in degrees N and W, so degrees S and E will be taken as negatives) and a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD (from Jan 1, 2000 onwards) and it will spit out two times in 24hr format for the sunrise and sunset.

e.g. For today in Sydney, Australia

```
riseset -33.87 -151.2 2013-12-27

05:45 20:09
```

Bonuses:
-100 if you can factor in elevation
-100 if you can factor daylight savings

The code MUST spit out times in the relevant time zone specified in the input based off the latitude and longitude OR in the client machine's own time zone.

Comment: Wait, what, we have to do a [latitude x longitude] => [timezone] lookup? Do we get a data file for that? Or a server we can access? Or is there a language that has such stuff built in? Can you tell us which one? Or we have to memorize the timezone boundaries? To what precision? Where do we get this data? Do you realize this data will take up most of the code length? What about coordinates that fall exactly on the timezone boundary? Say, the geographic poles? Also, what behavior is allowed when the input is a polar region during a polar night / day? What about out-of-range coordinates?

Comment: I would _love_ the challenge to calculate the horizon based on a point above an idealised sphere, but I _hate_ the associated challenge to find, hand-compress, programatically decopmress and then look up in, a timezone lookup map. Unless, of course, we can use idealized timezones (the offset is chosen so that the sun is the highest during noon, then it is rounded to the nearest hour) as well.

Comment: Maybe if we could output in the time zone the client's machine currently uses... ?

Comment: Is this even possible? Is there some "sunset algorithm"? :-P

Comment: @JanDvorak Use whatever you can, if the language you use can exploit the client's time zone then by all means do so...

Comment: If anyone wants a reference point, the Sunrise/Sunset Equation can be found at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio please avoid linking to mobile versions of sites

Comment: What is the desired behavior for polar regions when it's a polar day/night?

Comment: Hmm... my first estimates for the sunset went 12 years into the future - turns out I forgot  a term. Then I guessed 2 months.  Nurns out a forgotten coefficient was the cause. Now it's telling me the sunrise was at 4 AM despite it being mid-winter here. Maybe a forgotten minus sign or I'm using the wrong kind of Julian days? When I find out, I'll start minifying.

Comment: (by the way, it's hard to come up with 20 different at least somewhat mnemonic variable names)

Comment: To the unanswered clarification questions add the precision of input and output, the permitted error, the model of the globe (WGS84?), the date range which must be supported.

Comment: Isn't west longitude usually negative and east positive?

Comment: Here is a tool that does exactly the same: http://www.weatherimages.org/latlonsun.html

Comment: Time and time zones are [famously complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) and change all the time.  In fact they have changed since this was written.  I think that there is an interesting challenge here but as stated the complexities of time zones are not up to the site's current standards of clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent quite some time writing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from math import *


class RiseSet(object):

    __ZENITH = {'official': 90.833,
                'civil': '96',
                'nautical': '102',
                'astronomical': '108'}

    def __init__(self, day, month, year, latitude, longitude, daylight=False,
                 elevation=840, zenith='official'):
        ''' elevation is set to 840 (m) because that is the mean height of land above the sea level '''

        if abs(latitude) > 63.572375290155:
            raise ValueError('Invalid latitude: {0}.'.format(latitude))

        if zenith not in self.__ZENITH:
            raise ValueError('Invalid zenith value, must be one of {0}.'.format
                            (self.__ZENITH.keys()))

        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.daylight = daylight
        self.elevation = elevation
        self.zenith = zenith

    def getZenith(self):
        return cos(radians(self.__ZENITH[self.zenith]))

    def dayOfTheYear(self):
        n0 = floor(275*self.month/9)
        n1 = floor((self.month + 9) / 12)
        n2 = (1 + floor((self.year - 4*floor(self.year/4) + 2) / 3))
        return n0 - (n1*n2) + self.day - 30

    def approxTime(self):
        sunrise = self.dayOfTheYear() + ((6 - (self.longitude/15.0)) / 24)
        sunset = self.dayOfTheYear() + ((18 - (self.longitude/15.0)) / 24)
        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def sunMeanAnomaly(self):
        sunrise = (0.9856 * self.approxTime()[0]) - 3.289
        sunset = (0.9856 * self.approxTime()[1]) - 3.289
        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def sunTrueLongitude(self):
        sma = self.sunMeanAnomaly()
        sunrise = sma[0] + (1.916*sin(radians(sma[0]))) + \
                  (0.020*sin(radians(2*sma[0]))) + 282.634

        if sunrise < 0:
            sunrise += 360
        if sunrise > 360:
            sunrise -= 360

        sunset = sma[1] + (1.916*sin(radians(sma[1]))) + \
                 (0.020*sin(radians(2*sma[1]))) + 282.634

        if sunset <= 0:
            sunset += 360
        if sunset > 360:
            sunset -= 360

        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def sunRightAscension(self):
        stl = self.sunTrueLongitude()
        sunrise = atan(radians(0.91764*tan(radians(stl[0]))))

        if sunrise <= 0:
            sunrise += 360
        if sunrise > 360:
            sunrise -= 360

        sunset = atan(radians(0.91764*tan(radians(stl[1]))))

        if sunset <= 0:
            sunset += 360
        if sunset > 360:
            sunset -= 360

        sunrise_stl_q = (floor(stl[0]/90)) * 90
        sunrise_ra_q = (floor(sunrise/90)) * 90
        sunrise = sunrise + (sunrise_stl_q - sunrise_ra_q)
        sunrise = sunrise/15.0

        sunset_stl_q = (floor(stl[1]/90)) * 90
        sunset_ra_q = (floor(sunset/90)) * 90
        sunset = sunrise + (sunset_stl_q - sunset_ra_q)
        sunset /= 15.0

        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def sunDeclination(self):
        sunrise_sin_dec = 0.39782 * sin(radians(self.sunTrueLongitude()[0]))
        sunrise_cos_dec = cos(radians(asin(radians(sunrise_sin_dec))))

        sunset_sin_dec = 0.39782 * sin(radians(self.sunTrueLongitude()[1]))
        sunset_cos_dec = cos(radians(asin(radians(sunrise_sin_dec))))

        return (sunrise_sin_dec, sunrise_cos_dec,
                sunset_sin_dec, sunset_cos_dec)

    def sunHourAngle(self):
        sd = self.sunDeclination()
        sunrise_cos_h = (cos(radians(self.getZenith())) - (sd[0]* \
                         sin(radians(self.latitude))) / (sd[1]* \
                         cos(radians(self.latitude))))
        if sunrise_cos_h > 1:
            raise Exception('The sun never rises on this location.')

        sunset_cos_h = (cos(radians(self.getZenith())) - (sd[2]* \
                         sin(radians(self.latitude))) / (sd[3]* \
                         cos(radians(self.latitude))))
        if sunset_cos_h < -1:
            raise Exception('The sun never sets on this location.')

        sunrise = 360 - acos(radians(sunrise_cos_h))
        sunrise /= 15.0

        sunset = acos(radians(sunrise_cos_h))
        sunset /= 15.0

        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def localMeanTime(self):
        sunrise = self.sunHourAngle()[0] + self.sunRightAscension()[0] - \
                 (0.06571*self.approxTime()[0]) - 6.622
        sunset = self.sunHourAngle()[1] + self.sunRightAscension()[1] - \
                 (0.06571*self.approxTime()[1]) - 6.622
        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def convertToUTC(self):
        sunrise = self.localMeanTime()[0] - (self.longitude/15.0)

        if sunrise <= 0:
            sunrise += 24
        if sunrise > 24:
            sunrise -= 24

        sunset = self.localMeanTime()[1] - (self.longitude/15.0)

        if sunset <= 0:
            sunset += 24
        if sunset > 24:
            sunset -= 24

        return (sunrise, sunset)

    def __str__(self):
        return None
```

Now it's not yet functional (I screwed up some calculations) - I'll come back to it later (if I'll still have the courage) to [complete it / comment it](http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm).

Also, some interesting resources that I found while researching the subject:

- [How to compute planetary positions](http://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/ppcomp.html)
- [How to adjust sunrise and sunset times according to altitude?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30259/how-to-adjust-sunrise-and-sunset-times-according-to-altitude)
- [How To Convert a Decimal to Sexagesimal](http://geography.about.com/library/howto/htdegrees.htm)
- [When is the right ascension of the mean sun 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/when-is-the-right-ascension-of-the-mean-sun-0)
- [How do sunrise and sunset times change with altitude?](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=388)
- [What is the maximum length of latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965166/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-latitude-and-longitude)
- [Computation of Daylengths, Sunrise/Sunset Times, Twilight and Local
  Noon](http://www.sci.fi/~benefon/sol.html)
- [Position of the Sun](http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/sun.html)

Comment: I just saw your comment of `# It's late, I'm tired, and OP is a prick for asking me to do this.`

There was no obligation to do this task... Please don't put comments like this in your code... It does not sit favorably with other coders... including me.

I admire the fact that you gave it a red hot go, and the other links you've provided, but please do not use comments like this ever again...

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio You have my apologies.

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio I did not intend to offend you. I would also like to thank you for giving me an absolutely fantastic idea to research and code. Now I want to turn this into a self-standing python module (with sys arguments and so on). It turns out to be a little more complicated than I previously thought, but I intend to pull this off. Thank you again.

Comment: @Alex, do you realize this challenge is a year old? I'm pretty sure he won.

Comment: @mbomb007: Didn't realize.