# Rise and Shine!

Tags: code-golf, math, date

#### Challenge

The challenge is to create a program which takes a date, a latitude, and a longitude, and prints the time of the sunrise on that date for the given location.

The program must work for any valid date between January 1, 2000, and December 31, 2999.

Internal and external sunrise functions are disallowed. Date libraries are allowed only to format the output into ISO 8601, and to determine the local time from utc

#### Clarifications

- You do not need to take into account altitude or the refraction of light from the sun.
- Date input and output must be in correct [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format
- The date, latitude, and longitude will be given as a space separated string, in that order, on stdin
- Printing a value means outputting to stdout
- The output should have a precision of +/- 1 minute
- The time outputted must be in the local time of the location specified, and include the local time zone offset

  #### Bonus

  - **Score * 0.1** if you do not use a date library at all

#### Resources

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation
- http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/solareqns.PDF

#### Test Cases

```
Input                                        Output
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-03-19                  2265-03-19T06:05-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2265-03-06                  2265-03-06T06:31-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-03-14                      2265-03-14T06:41-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-03-05                  2265-03-05T06:28-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-02-19                      2265-02-19T07:19-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-02-06                      2265-02-06T07:37-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-02-14                  2265-02-14T06:57-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-02-05                  2265-02-05T07:08-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-10-19                      2265-10-19T06:47-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2265-10-06                  2265-10-06T06:07-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2265-10-14                  2265-10-14T06:16-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2265-10-05                  2265-10-05T06:06-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-05-19                      2265-05-19T04:58-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-05-06                      2265-05-06T05:13-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2265-05-14                  2265-05-14T04:50-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-05-05                      2265-05-05T05:14-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-08-19                  2265-08-19T05:14-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-08-06                      2265-08-06T05:23-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2265-08-14                      2265-08-14T05:32-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2265-08-05                  2265-08-05T04:59-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2400-03-19                  2400-03-19T06:12-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-03-06                      2400-03-06T07:01-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-03-14                      2400-03-14T06:47-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-03-05                  2400-03-05T06:39-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-02-19                  2400-02-19T07:01-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-02-06                  2400-02-06T07:17-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-02-14                  2400-02-14T07:08-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-02-05                      2400-02-05T07:46-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-10-19                      2400-10-19T06:54-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2400-10-06                  2400-10-06T06:11-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-10-14                  2400-10-14T06:23-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-10-05                      2400-10-05T06:38-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-05-19                      2400-05-19T05:06-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2400-05-06                  2400-05-06T04:58-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-05-14                  2400-05-14T04:57-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2400-05-05                  2400-05-05T04:59-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-08-19                  2400-08-19T05:29-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2400-08-06                  2400-08-06T05:16-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2400-08-14                      2400-08-14T05:40-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2400-08-05                  2400-08-05T05:07-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-03-19                  2733-03-19T06:39-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-03-06                  2733-03-06T07:01-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2733-03-14                      2733-03-14T07:15-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2733-03-05                      2733-03-05T07:30-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-02-19                  2733-02-19T07:27-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-02-06                  2733-02-06T07:43-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-02-14                  2733-02-14T07:30-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-02-05                  2733-02-05T07:44-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-10-19                  2733-10-19T06:55-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-10-06                  2733-10-06T06:37-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-10-14                  2733-10-14T06:46-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2733-10-05                      2733-10-05T07:04-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-05-19                  2733-05-19T05:12-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-05-06                  2733-05-06T05:33-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-05-14                  2733-05-14T05:25-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2733-05-05                      2733-05-05T05:49-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-08-19                  2733-08-19T05:55-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-08-06                  2733-08-06T05:35-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2733-08-14                  2733-08-14T05:43-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2733-08-05                  2733-08-05T05:42-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-03-19                  2455-03-19T06:21-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-03-06                  2455-03-06T06:42-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-03-14                  2455-03-14T06:24-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-03-05                  2455-03-05T06:43-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2455-02-19                      2455-02-19T07:30-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-02-06                  2455-02-06T07:20-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-02-14                  2455-02-14T07:11-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-02-05                  2455-02-05T07:21-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-10-19                  2455-10-19T06:32-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-10-06                  2455-10-06T06:14-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-10-14                  2455-10-14T06:27-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-10-05                  2455-10-05T06:13-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-05-19                  2455-05-19T04:48-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2455-05-06                      2455-05-06T05:24-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2455-05-14                  2455-05-14T05:01-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-05-05                  2455-05-05T05:03-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-08-19                  2455-08-19T05:25-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2455-08-06                  2455-08-06T05:12-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2455-08-14                      2455-08-14T05:43-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2455-08-05                      2455-08-05T05:33-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-03-19                  2015-03-19T05:57-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-03-06                  2015-03-06T06:23-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-03-14                  2015-03-14T06:06-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2015-03-05                      2015-03-05T06:49-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-02-19                  2015-02-19T06:42-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2015-02-06                      2015-02-06T07:30-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-02-14                  2015-02-14T06:49-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-02-05                  2015-02-05T07:03-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-10-19                  2015-10-19T06:12-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-10-06                  2015-10-06T05:58-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-10-14                  2015-10-14T06:03-06:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-10-05                  2015-10-05T05:53-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-05-19                  2015-05-19T04:37-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-05-06                  2015-05-06T04:42-06:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-05-14                  2015-05-14T04:41-05:00
40.6643 -73.9385 2015-05-05                  2015-05-05T04:51-05:00
41.8376 -87.6818 2015-08-19                  2015-08-19T05:04-06:00
43.65 -79.38 2015-08-06                      2015-08-06T05:13-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2015-08-14                      2015-08-14T05:22-05:00
43.65 -79.38 2015-08-05                      2015-08-05T05:12-05:00
```

This is code-golf, so least bytes wins.

Comment: Highly related (possible duplicate?): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16209/3808

Comment: @Doorknob Wasn't aware of it, but that is extremely similar. Is it too much so to keep the question up? (I assume yes)

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to golf the local time zone without a date library.

Comment: @KennyTM well spotted that's a huge issue, for example crossing the border from China to Pakistan the official time changes by 3 hours. Globby, do you want official time or "longitude-correct" time?

Comment: The second website you linked has several different values for the "zenith", one of the inputs. Which one should we use?

Comment: @KennyTM removed from the question

Comment: @KSFT use the official

Comment: Which one do you consider "official"?

Comment: @KSFT 90.833 degrees